# Spark Dataframe : Pivot with sorting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, pivot

I am reading the following `json` file into Dataframe in spark:

```
{"id" : "a", "country" : "uk", "date" : "2016-01-01"}
{"id" : "b", "country" : "uk", "date" : "2016-01-02"}
{"id" : "c", "country" : "fr", "date" : "2016-02-01"}
{"id" : "d", "country" : "de", "date" : "2016-03-01"}
{"id" : "e", "country" : "tk", "date" : "2016-04-01"}
{"id" : "f", "country" : "be", "date" : "2016-05-01"}
{"id" : "g", "country" : "nl", "date" : "2016-06-01"}
{"id" : "h", "country" : "uk", "date" : "2016-06-01"}
```

I then apply `groupBy` on it and pivot it on date, here's the (pseudo) code:

```
val df = spark.read.json("file.json")
val dfWithFormattedDate = df.withColumn("date", date_format(col("date"), "yyyy-MM"))
dfWithFormattedDate.groupBy("country").pivot("date").agg(countDistinct("id").alias("count")).orderBy("country")
```

This gives me the `Dataframe` with country and pivoted dates (months) as columns. I would then like to `order` the results in descending order of total count. However, I don't have `count` as one of the columns and I can't apply `pivot` after applying `count()` on groupBy as it returns `Dataset` and not `RelationalGroupedDataset`. I have tried the following as well:

`dfWithFormattedDate.groupBy("country").pivot("date").count()`

This does not give me `count` column either. Is there any way I can gave both `count` and pivoted dates in resultant Dataset so that I can order by count desc?

**Update**

Here's the current output:

```
country|2016-01|2016-02|2016-03| ....
   fr  | null  |  1    | null  | 
   be  | null  |  null | null  |
   uk  | 2     |  null | null  |
```

Here's the expected output:

```
country|count|2016-01|2016-02|2016-03| ....
   uk  |  3  | 2     |  null | null  | 
   fr  |  1  | null  |  1    | null  | 
   be  |  1  | null  |  null | null  |
```

As you can see, I need the `count` column in the result and order the rows in descending order of `count`. Ordering without explicitly having `count` column is fine as well.

Comment: I don't quite catch your order relation. Would you care giving an example ?

Comment: `dfWithFormattedDate.groupBy("country").pivot("date")` this does not give anything, what's the following aggregation?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @all Added current and desired output.

Comment: @mtoto this is the complete aggregation : `dfWithFormattedDate.groupBy("country").pivot("date").agg(countDistinct("id").alias("count")).orderBy("country").na.fill(0)` I have omitted `id` for brevity.

Comment: @mtoto updated the example and added `id` in json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If our starting point is this `DataFrame` :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{date_format ,col, countDistinct}

val result = df.withColumn("date", date_format(col("date"), "yyyy-MM"))
               .groupBy("country").pivot("date").agg(countDistinct("id").alias("count"))
               .na.fill(0)
```

We then can simply calculate the rowsum for all the columns excluding the `country` column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc

val test = result.withColumn("count", 
  result.columns.filter(_!="country")
                .map(c => col(c))
                .reduce((x, y) => x + y))
        .orderBy(desc("count"))

test.show()
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|country|2016-01|2016-02|2016-03|2016-04|2016-05|2016-06|count|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|     uk|      2|      0|      0|      0|      0|      1|    3|
|     be|      0|      0|      0|      0|      1|      0|    1|
|     de|      0|      0|      1|      0|      0|      0|    1|
|     tk|      0|      0|      0|      1|      0|      0|    1|
|     nl|      0|      0|      0|      0|      0|      1|    1|
|     fr|      0|      1|      0|      0|      0|      0|    1|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looks great. Can we somehow calculate the counts *before* pivoting? The reason being, dates won't be in the same format. Dateformat will be passed by user as an argument to the method so it can be `dd-MM-yyyy` or `MM-yyyy` or anything.

Comment: I ended up doing this: `var countPerCountry = dfWithFormattedDate.groupBy("country").agg(countDistinct("id").alias("count")); dfWithFormattedDate.join(countPerCountry, "country").groupBy("country", "count").pivot("date").agg(countDistinct("id")).orderBy(col("count").desc).na.fill(0)`, guess it's similar to what you suggested

Comment: Except you are creating an extra join step that is not necessary and will be  less efficient.

Comment: Will it not be the same as we are doing two `reduce` operations anyway? I agree there's a `join` but it's an inner `join` so should be quick?

Comment: you can always post your own solution and accept it if that's what you prefer.

Comment: It's not about posting my own solution (I have accepted your answer btw), I just wanted to check whether `join` will degrade the performance drastically with the bottomline being we need to perform two `reduce` operations anyway? I am new to `spark` so just wanted to know your thoughts.

Comment: @DarshanMehta Join will degrade performance. There is an overkill in using it in this context